# Handle repeated options like -v -vv -vvv idiomatically with perl Getopt

Tags: perl, getopt

I'd like to handle the verbosity level option like OpenSSH does: by multiply passing the `-v` option.

`Getopt::Std` does not increment no-argument option values, but simply sets them to `1`. This means that passing `-vvv` with Getopt::Std will yield `$opt_v == 1` and I need it to be `3` in that case.

`Getopt::Long` with the `v+` option-spec understands `-v -v` correctly (target variable ends up `2`), but it misunderstands `-vvv` as the option named `vvv` -- which is not defined and causes an error.

How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I figured out the answer after writing up the question, but before posting it -- classic.</sub>

---

The best way to handle this is to use `Getopt::Long` with `bundling`:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(:config bundling);
GetOptions ("v+" => \$verbose);
```

This handles `-v -vv -vvv` as expected: `$verbose == 6`.

---

If for some reason you cannot use or prefer not to use `bundling`, the only other way is to define the options `vv`, `vvv` etc. up to a reasonable maximum:

```
use Getopt::Long;
GetOptions (
    "v+" => \$verbose);
    "vv" => sub { $verbose += 2 },
    "vvv" => sub { $verbose += 3 },
);
```

This then also handles `-v -vv -vvv` as expected: `$verbose == 6`.